# Continuity of $f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

So, I need to prove that the function-
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
 \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x-y} & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
 0 & (x,y) =(0,0)\\
\end{cases}$$
is discontinuous at the origin. But to me it seems like this is continuous there. I tried solving this in the following manner.
Suppose we approach the origin along the line $y=mx$, thus $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)=\lim_{x \to 0}  \dfrac{x(1+m^2)}{1-m}$$
Isn't the above expression $=0$ for all values of $m$. Then why is this function discontinuous at the origin as my textbook says?

Comment: What is $f(1,1)$?

Comment: It's undefined.

Comment: $f$ is continuous iff ALL curves passing through the origin give the same value of the limit. $y=mx$ is only one family of curves (the straight lines)

Comment: @player3236 then how would I know which curves do not pass through it? Is it just a method of trial and error?

Comment: There are some tricks; one is shown in the answer below: making the polynomial in the denominator a higher degree than the one in the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$f(y+y^3,y)=y^3+2y+\frac2y$$and that therefore$$\lim_{y\to0^+}f(y+y^3,y)=\infty.$$

Comment: Nice answer. Although I would want to ask you if there is any set method for solving these problems, or is it simply looking at the problem empirically suggests the solution?

Comment: My approach is based on the fact that if $(x,y)$ is very close to a point of the form $(a,a)$, then the quotient $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x-y}$ is likely to bee very high. That's why I chose points of the form $(y+y^3,y)$, which are close to $(y,y)$.